# Addplot3 connects the endpoints

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[domain=0:10] (x, 25, {x^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

How do I remove the line between the endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `samples y=0` removes the line connecting the endpoints.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3 [
                domain=0:10,
                % ----------
                % add `samples y=0' to remove the line connecting the endpoints
                samples y=0,
                % ----------
            ] (x, 25, {x^2});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]